# Combine two directives together

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'd like to use the given model-data by the formControlName-directive with my own directive.

```
<input type="text"
       formControlName="endDate"
       my-directive>
```

Is there a way to access the formControl-value in the directive? In a component it's very easy using ControlValueAccessors...

Comment: What do you mean by "toghether". If more than one directive matches all are applied.

Comment: What exactly you are asking ? you want to pass `endDate` to directive to use it in logic.

Comment: using my-directive, how to access the formControlName?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a matching input and you will get the value passed:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]'
})
class MyDirective {
  @Input() formControlName:String;

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.formControlName);
  }
}
```